# How do you declare a variable asynchronously in javascript?

Tags: javascript, promise, firefox-addon-webextensions

So I have a bunch of really large lists in JavaScript that I am loading in a webextension. Unfortunately, they are so large that they slow down page load, at about 5 ms per list. While small, I'd like to get rid of that time on load and load the variables asynchronously in a promise to use them later.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) have a method to create a Promise from any object, Promise.resolve(). For example, with my very large lists, let's assume I have three functions called createList1, createList2, and createList3 that create and return a very large list. I can then create those lists asynchronously, aggregate them, and use them when after the method is called and the promise is resolved by:

```
// use a closure for good practice.
let closure = (function() {
    // create the promises when the script is loaded
    var x = Promise.resolve(createList1());
    var y = Promise.resolve(createList2());
    var z = Promise.resolve(createList3());
    // aggregate all promises into one promise
    return Promise.all([x,y,z]);
})();

function doSomething(listOfLargeLists) {
    // given the list very large lists, do something with each of them
    // do stuff here, e.g. var actualList1 = listOfLargeLists[0];
}

closure.then((listOfLargeLists) => {
    doSomething(listOfLargeLists);
});
```

If you just want to declare one variable asynchronously, you just have to create it in a promise and then whenever you want to use it, use a then:

```
var x = Promise.resolve(createList1());

function doSomething(bigList) {
    // do something with the list
}

function doSomethingDifferent(bigList) {
    // do something different with the list
}

var y = x.then((bigList) => {
    doSomething(bigList);
});

// Async with y
var z = x.then((bigList) => {
    doSomethingDifferent(bigList);
});

// Or Wait for y first and use its return value
var yUpdate = y.then((bigList) => {
    doSomethingDifferent(bigList);
});
```

Comment: Why did you attach this to the answer section?

Comment: The encapsulation of `closure` is not necessary in your answer, FYI. The scope of that function will still be private without the function encapsulation you are using.

Comment: `"declare variable asynchronously"`  makes no sense, you've made up a non-problem and answered it poorly